# Same part devices supporting different temperature ranges

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, temperature

I just had this question.
We often come across microcontrollers having the same internal peripherals and supporting the same functions but supporting different temperature ranges.

Can you tell me how the same microcontrollers having the same functions can support different temperature ranges? Like, what is changed internally as all the peripherals are the same?

Comment: Usually nothing, it's just the better performing parts get assigned the wider temperature ranges as companies can charge more for them. So it isn't any change, it's just the parts which have happened to be manufacutred with fewer defects. I have no evidence for this other than conversations with suppliers, hence this being a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Puffafish There's lots of urban legends like that, but in practice how would the manufacturer know if something fails a certain temperature range but decide to sell it anyway? It would be a cumbersome process to implement - they would have to identify single failing parts and also design non-destructive temperature tests. In practice I think it's more like: "these parts that you bought have actually been temperature tested as an extra step during production". It's for example common practice for automotive qual that all parts leaving the factory are tested.

Comment: @Lundin Temperatures tests are typically nondestructive. The way parts usually fail at extreme temperature is because of timing violations, failed dc parameters, or something like that. Whether it makes sense to bin the parts like this would depend on what the yield curve looks like and how high the price differential is.

Answer (score 1):

If all parts could be rated from -40 to +85 or more they would. But they can't because of several reasons.

- material or process limitations in order to prevent frost microcracks with moisture creepage in plastic seals. Sumitomo, Japan has improved a lot in the last 50 years to make plastic seals as the major supplier to all chip fabs.  The critical thermal requirement is to block humidity and avoid popcorn failures when frozen. At one time only ceramic packages could block moisture ingress.  The supplier of plastic thus makes a difference in cost and temperature range.
- All logic is really analog and PN junctions have a negative temperature coefficient and Bipolar runs faster hot, while CMOS runs faster colder.  As such, ADC tolerances and resolutions may limit the temperature range.  For analog circuits, there may be other analog bias currents that exceed a competitive spec for consumer temperature but do not meet a mil-spec temperature or industrial range in a batch of wafers so sorting may be involved.
- There may be specific reasons for different parts.